# New XCode install not showing simulators

Tags: ios, xcode

Brand new XCode 13.3 install on MBP M1. Developers tools are installed as well.
When I click on Xcode->Preferences-Components I get the screen below...

[image]

Clicking on "Check and Install now" button spins for about 2 seconds and then stops.  Nothing happens.  Any ideas?

This area is new to me. I am trying to set up Appium for mobile testing and I need the simulators to access from.

Comment: Might just be a network hiccup. I was having trouble getting to Apple's developer web sites a little while ago; try again in an hour or two if it doesn't work now.

Comment: Retry now. Apple services seems back to normal.

Comment: Thank you both, it seems to be working now.  Simulator list is showing, downloading is taking forever but at least it is working.